# How to save data for anonymous user in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm working on a specific project on Laravel and I need to store some user data even before user would like to authenticate. For example it can be city or delivery point.

In my opinion the best way to do this is to allow users to be saved to database without such properties as name, email or password. But I also think that this is a crunch and the best practice exists and needs to be used.

If so, help me please to find a way to solve a problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Save it in the session

Comment: Or some client storage like `LocalStorage`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the session helper function for that purpose.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#using-the-session

```
$someCity = post("city",'none');
session('city',$someCity);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Via a request instance...**

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

**Via the global helper...**

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

**Pushing To Array Session Values**

```
$request->session()->push('user.teams', 'developers');
```